# Deleting a specific managed object from persistence store ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, persistent-storage

I am particularly new to using Core Data in IOS and I have stumbled across an issue that I can not seem to solve. If there has already been a post about this I do apologize in advance I have looked as hard as I possibly could have without breaking my computer out of frustration. Let us say I have two different view controllers, View Controller 1 and View Controller 2. Furthermore, View Controller 1 has a "next" button that takes a user to View Controller 2. In View Controller 1, I create a managed object A and do a save, so now my persistent store is updated with the new managed object A. After hitting next, in the view did load method of View Controller 2, I would like to delete this object A that I created and saved in the previous view controller. How exactly can I do this and what is the best method? The only solution I have been able to come up with is to do the following:

1) After creating my managed object A, setting its attributes and saving, I could grab the "id" of the object I just created.

2) After grabbing this "id", I can pass this NSManagedObjectId to View Controller 2 in the prepareForSegue method, and then use the id in ViewController2 later to do my deletion work.

Is this the only way/correct way to do this, there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Get the instance of the managed object that you create and pass that to the second view controller. When you want to delete it:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObject.managedObjectContext;
[moc deleteObject:self.managedObject];
[moc save:&error];
```

Comment: how do I get the instance of the managed object that I create? I only know how to create a managed object instance using "insertNewObjectForEntityName: inManagedObjectContext:" but after I create the managed object how do I grab an instance of what I just created. This is essentially the crux of my problem.

Comment: The method returns the new instance. Do you understand what a pointer is? And what an instance actually is?

Comment: Here maybe pasting a little code snippet will help. I have tried following your advice and my object is still not getting deleted. In view Controller 1, I get an instance of the managed object that I created by doing the following:                         CurrentUser *user = (CurrentUser *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CurrentUser" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];                   self.managed_object_instance = user (managed_object_instance is NSManagedObject)                              Is this how I would get the instance of the object I created?

Comment: Yes, `user` is the instance of the `CurrentUser` entity. How are you determining if the object gets deleted?

Comment: What I do is I then pass self.managed_object_instance over to the second view controller in the prepareForSegue method. After passing it over I call a function in the viewdidLoad() method of the 2nd view controller that essentially deletes the object and saves. Then I try to perform a fetch on the MOC, and if the fetch query results in an empty array then the object has been deleted from my store. I have noticed this only works for me if I completely reset the simulators content and settings, otherwise the object I am passing over never gets deleted, or maybe it is but its not getting written.

Comment: There is some fundamental I am not grasping/understanding when saving and deleting. I cant put a finger on it. Furthermore my second view controller is NOT a tableview controller just a plain view controller, every core data example I have seen has the second view controller set up as a table view controller, and they simply delete objects using the "tableview deleterow at indexpath" method. My case is not as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this; without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, I can only give some general comments.

Firstly, passing an id into View Controller 2 probably isn't very desirable if there's another way of doing it, because you're exposing implementation details at a view controller level.

Is there not a way of querying Core Data from VC2 and finding out what it is you need to delete that way?

Comment: this is exactly what I am trying to figure out, I do not know how to do that and you are right I do not want to keep passing my NSManagedObjectID's between view controllers back and forth neither do I want to keep passing the managed object back and forth. I really do not know the best way to go about this